# Get attributes from previous and next parent siblings and maintain order

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a html structure like this:

```
<a href="/target"><img src ='image1.png' /></a>
<a href="/target1"><img src ='image2.png' /></a>
<a href="/target2"><img id="img3" src ='image3.png' /></a>
<a href="/target3"><img src ='image3.png' /></a>
<a href="/target4"><img src ='image5.png' /></a>
```

Let's say someone clicks on #img3.
I need to get all `href`attributes form the previous and next images.

May final goal is to get an array where all src's are listed. Beginning with the Image, I clicked on.

My Idea was, to get the prevois hrefs, the current one is known, and the next ones.
With these ones, i want to build an array.

It is important, that the order of the hrefs is beeing maintained.

An example (#img was clicked):

The array shall look like this:

`var hrefs = [target2,target3,target4,target,target1];`

Another example (image5.png) was clicked:

The array of hrefs shall be build and look like this.

`var hrefs  = [target4,target,target1,target2,target3];`

Try to imagine, that the images are placed on a circle. The Order, I am talking about is clockwise.

Maybe there is a better way, than my one.

Another idea is to build an array with all hrefs and reindex(build new index) it by setting the known element an index of 0.

Any help is welcome

Comment: `I need to get all hrefattributes`, `May final goal is to get an array where all src's are listed` so do you need hrefs or src?

Comment: @Kevin B Please have alook at my edit.

Comment: That does make a lot more sense, thanks. i'll clear my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('img').on('click', function(e){

    var $this = $(this),
        $closest = $this.closest('a'),
        $prev = $closest.prevAll('a'),
        $next = $closest.nextAll('a'),
        result = [$closest[0]].concat($next.get()).concat($prev.get().reverse()),
        hrefs = $(result).map(function(i, e){ return e.href; }).get();

    console.log(result, hrefs);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEcm4/2/

Perhaps not the prettiest solution, but hey.

Update for image source array: http://jsfiddle.net/rEcm4/3/

Comment: @user998163 From the `hrefs` array. But you want the image sources, right?

Comment: It is a kind of Lightbox function, so the href attribute is okay, as it point to the large version of the image.

Comment: @user998163 Updated with an img `src` version as well in case you need it.